# Can't connect through wired connection

Tags: networking

I used to be able to connect to wireless networks and wired networks (although my wireless network had problems; see my other question). Then, one day, the section Wired Networks just disappeared! And when I plugin a cable, nothing happens! Why?

Despite having worked a while, [the answer below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9221/cant-connect-through-wired-connection/9227#9227) seems to have stopped working for me. Therefore, my question is still active, and I anxiously await any replies.

Comment: Can you add some hardware information to your question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: Any specifics? I'm not sure where to start, as I don't know what has changed in the meantime.

Comment: Anything in those log files that mention networking stuff, like the kind of hardware the network card is, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and make sure it looks like this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
```

It sounds like it's blocking network-manager from configuring the interface.

Comment: No, wait, it only worked a few hours and a few restarts. Four hours later, I booted up my computer to see that it was as before, and worse: this time, when I checked the file, auto eth0 was still there! So that means the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Hold on... It's back again. What the...

Comment: when i input the code it says permission denied

Comment: You have to have admin rights to edit the file. Use something like gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces